# Searching Items at List has Lists in it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to do contact book for a little project.
I have a list that has lists in it, like:

```
Contact_List = [["Smith", "John", "780 555 3234", "jsmith@gsacrd.ab.ca"], ["Pitts", "Harry", "780 555 7329", "hpitts@gmail.com"], ["Fields", "Sara", "780 555 8129", "sfields@hotmail.com"], ["Smith", "Jane", "780 555 2819", "jsmith@gmail.com"], ["Unger", "Felix", "302 555 3819", "funger@universal.org"]]
```

So, I want to do search by name or last name, and I want to print that specific contact.

```
def SearchByName():
  print "Search Contact by the Name"
  name = raw_input("Enter the name :")
  def search(name[0], name[-1]):
      for x in Contact_list:
          if (x[0] == first) and (x[1] == last):
              print 'contact found it'
              print x[2], x[3]
          else:
              print "This Contact Does Not Exist!!"
```

and it's always printing

```
"This Contact Does Not Exist!!"
```

and there is an another def named `SearchByLastname`
so if we can fix that I can edit for

Comment: `def search(name[0], name[-1]):` is invalid syntax. Where is the actual code you are running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use split, if there is space between first and last name entered by user

```
name = raw_input("Enter the name :").split()
```

your code should be like this:

```
def SearchByName():
    print "Search Contact by the Name"
    name = raw_input("Enter the name :").split()
    search(name[0], name[-1])

def search(first, last):
    for x in Contact_list:
        if (x[0] == first) and (x[1] == last):
            print 'contact found it'
            print x[2], x[3]
            break
    else:
        print "This Contact Does Not Exist!!"
SearchByName()
```

Comment: Yeah it did bro thanks :) btw what if I only want to search for first name? Like searching by only first name?

Comment: @Bryan just  `and (x[1] == last)` remove this from the if statement

Comment: Thank you for everything m8. But last one more thing pls?  How to do Searching for a contact and deleting that spesific contact with numbers and email?

Answer (score 1):

In your solution you go to `else` block on each iteration when `if` condition is false.

Put `break` after a successful comparison and move `else` to be part of the loop.

This should do it:

```
    for x in Contact_list:
        if (x[0] == first) and (x[1] == last):
            print 'contact found it'
            print x[2], x[3]
            break
    else:
        print "This Contact Does Not Exist!!"
```

This will break after the first matching contact is found. If you need to find all matching contacts, the solution has to be reworked.